# Determine number of cores using Rust

Tags: rust, cpu-cores

I want to spawn a certain number of tasks based on the cores that a machine has.  Is there anything in Rust that can find the number of cores, or should I just run external commands and parse the output?

Comment: It would also be useful to have a standardized way for the number of threads to be configurable?  A combination of environmental variables and an overriding command line option.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

There's a crate to do this: num_cpus.

References:

- [crates.io page](https://crates.io/crates/num_cpus)
- [github.com source](https://github.com/seanmonstar/num_cpus)

Add this to your `Cargo.toml`:

```toml
[dependencies]
num_cpus = "1.0"
```

Then in your source:

```rust
extern crate num_cpus;
let num = num_cpus::get();
```

Comment: And if you want the number of physical cores: `num_cpus::get_physical()`

Answer (score 26):

You can use [`std::thread::available_parallelism`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/thread/fn.available_parallelism.html) as of Rust 1.59.0:

```
use std::thread::available_parallelism;
let default_parallelism_approx = available_parallelism().unwrap().get();
```

It returns 12 on my machine with a Ryzen 5 4600H which is quite consistent with the number of logical processors it has.

Answer (score 6):

You could use `std::os::num_cpus`. Example:

```
fn main() {
    println!("{}", std::os::num_cpus());
}
```

Comment: @Arjan: Oh, you are right. `default_sched_threads()` is public, however, and should be usable, more or less, for the OP purposes.

Comment: std::os::num_cpus is now gone, as is default_sched_threads, so the questions is now unanswered. The answers were good when presented, it is Rust that has changed.

Comment: https://docs.rs/num_cpus/1.4.0/num_cpus/index.html  "Replaces the deprecated functionality of std::os::num_cpus"

Answer (score 0):

It is now possible to use:

```
std::os::num_cpus

pub fn num_cpus() -> uint
```

---

Version of Rust:

```
$ rustc --version
rustc 0.13.0-nightly (d91a015ab 2014-11-14 23:37:27 +0000)
```

Reference:

[std::os::num_cpus](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/os/fn.num_cpus.html)

Comment: std::os::num_cpus is now gone, as is default_sched_threads, so the questions is now unanswered. The answers were good when presented, it is Rust that has changed.